# RabbitMQ error: "ssl_options.keyfile invalid, file does not exist or cannot be read by the node"

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-volume

I'm trying to add SSL to a RabbitMQ deployment via Docker Compose:

```
# rabbitmq.conf

ssl_options.certfile     = /container/path/to/certfile.crt
ssl_options.keyfile      = /container/path/to/keyfile.key
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.10.7-management
  ...
  volumes:
    - /host/path/to/certfile.crt:/container/path/to/certfile.crt
    - /host/path/to/keyfile.crt:/container/path/to/keyfile.key
    - ...
  ...
```

However, when spinning up the container, I get the error:

```
ssl_options.keyfile invalid, file does not exist or cannot be read by the node
```

I have double checked that the volume mounting is working, and that the `keyfile` is actually there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out to be a permissions issue. Solved by running in the host machine:

```
chmod 664 /host/path/to/certfile.crt
chmod 664 /host/path/to/keyfile.crt
```

Comment: How did you find this out? :) I spent quite some time to figure it out but did not see it. Thanks for sharing.